# Google Sheets: Date and time is seen as a text and cannot be coerced to a number

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I'm trying to format dates given to me in an excel spreadsheet, and some of the values are seen as a text. I've tried using the format option to set a date and time to the entire column.

[The Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7ZuPPlrE4cijuFRbfdFekR2LM4oXCZaMV9HuEVOj8o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the original format of column E before you have applied any formating? I think this might be a data error, as when i change the date formats round i.e. cell E9 from 4/15/22 to 15/04/22 it formats correctly. So the dates might be the wrong way round in your inital data

Comment: Thanks so much! The data that was given to me had the wrong format in dates. I switched the settings for the spreadsheet to US and the dates worked.

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(IF(A2:A="",,DATE(YEAR(E2:E), MONTH(E2:E), 1)),date("20" & REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E,".*\/(\d{2}) "),REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E,"\d+"),1)))}
```

Reference

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thanks! After I changed the settings on the spreadsheet to US, I was able to use your formula. Thank you.